# Unit test a function which downloads json file from s3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose

I have a function given as below:

```
def read_json(bucket, key):
    """

    :param bucket:
    :param key:
    :return:
    """
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    content_object = S3.Object(bucket, key)
    file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    json_content = json.loads(file_content)
    return json_content
```

I am testing this function as given below:

```
@mock.patch('boto3.resource')
def test_read_json(mock_resource):

    mock_resource.Object.return_value.return_value = '{ "key":"value", ' \
                                              '"key_1":value_1, ' \
                                              '"key_2":"value_2"}'
    json = helpers.read_json('bucket', 'key')
    mock_resource.assert_called_once_with('s3')
    tools.assert_is_instance(json, 'json')
```

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not MagicMock

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong over here ?

Comment: Can you please also share where `read_json` is embedded, i.e. in which module? Also where is `S3` initialised? I reckon this is a `S3 = boto3.resource('s3')`? Because you need to patch the `boto3.resource` of the module where `read_json` is located.

Comment: ```read_json``` is embedded in a helpers file . this is where ```S3 = boto3.resource('s3')``` is initialized.

Comment: Then you will need to do something like `@mock.patch('helpers.boto3.resource')`.

Comment: it says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'

Comment: Please share a bit more how your helpers file is structured, where the `S3` init is, how the imports look like and what your directory structure looks like so that users can help you.

Comment: I edited my question, mock seems to work now but got error on json

Comment: Did my answer help or do you still having issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my function slightly to achieve the same results:

```
def read_json(bucket, key):
    """

    :param bucket:
    :param key:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(bucket, key)
        file_content = response.get('Body').read().decode('utf-8')
        json_content = json.loads(file_content)
    except ClientError as ex:
        LOGGER.error("Received error: %s", ex)
        raise
    return json_content
```

Corresponding unit tests:

```
@mock.patch('delivery_qa.utils.helpers.s3.get_object')
def test_read_json(s3_get_mock):
    body_mock = Mock()
    body_mock.read.return_value.decode.return_value = json.dumps('response')
    # When first time function would be called, it would return body_mock
    s3_get_mock.side_effect = [{'Body': body_mock}]
    first_call = helpers.read_json('bucket', 'key')
    tools.assert_equal(first_call, 'response')


@raises(ClientError)
@mock.patch('delivery_qa.utils.helpers.s3.get_object')
def test_read_json_exception(s3_get_mock):
    body_mock = Mock()
    body_mock.read.return_value.decode.return_value = json.dumps('response')
    # When first time function would be called, it would return ClientError
    s3_get_mock.side_effect = [ClientError(MagicMock(), MagicMock())]
    helpers.read_json('bucket', 'key')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really not pretty but creating some mock classes will solve the problem:

```
class MockBody():
    def read(self):
        return '{ "key": "value", ' \
               '"key_1": "value_1", ' \
               '"key_2": "value_2" }'.encode('utf-8')


class MockBoto3Resource():
    class Object():
        def __init__(self, bucket, key):
            pass
        def get(self):
            return {'Body': MockBody()}
```

Then use it in your test like this:

```
@mock.patch('boto3.resource')
def test_read_json(mock_resource):
    mock_resource.return_value = MockBoto3Resource
    [...]
```

You might want to look at Stubber (https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html), I've personally never used it but you can probably make this more elegant by using `botocore.stub.Stubber`.